# Multiple display works in Linux Mint Live CD but not my Gentoo installation

Tags: xorg, kde, gentoo, intel, multi-monitor

I tried to connect a VGA display to my Gentoo laptop and use multi-display. However, the two screens behave like one big screen instead of two separate ones. That is, if I maximize a window, it crosses the screens.

In Linux Mint Live CD, however, they act like two screens. I tracked down the problem to every level including KDE, X, udev, and kernel but I can't find the problem.

I've asked the question on http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7446050.html , but seems that no one read it. The only difference I see is that my `xf86-video-intel` seems to recognize my card incorrectly, and not reading EDID from display, and not using `crtc`.

However, I tried combinations of kernels, configs, downgraded drivers, removing the nVidia drivers, etc., but none worked. Also, if I click "identify outputs" in KDE, both "LVDS1" and "VGA1" will display on BOTH screens, but on LiveCD LVDS1 displays on my laptop and VGA1 displays on the external screen.

- Why would this have happened?
- Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem is solved. I added USE="xinerama" globally and recompiled world. The affected packages includes but not limited to qtgui and gtk+, these should be the main packages that changes the result. So simpile...